# How can i search inside array of array object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a booking array of arrays that contain objects and I have to search inside the array using `searchValue`
could you please help me here

here we have to check the booking id if booking id and `searchValue` matched we have to push that object into result array.

```js
let bookingArr = [
  [{
      name: "user 1",
      bookingid: 10,
      product: "ab"
    },
    {
      name: "user 1",
      bookingid: 10,
      product: "cd"
    }
  ],
  [{
      name: "user 2",
      bookingid: 11,
      product: "ui"
    },
    {
      name: "user 1",
      bookingid: 10,
      product: "ef"
    }
  ],
  [{
      name: "user 3",
      bookingid: 12,
      product: "ui"
    },
    {
      name: "user 4",
      bookingid: 13,
      product: "ef"
    }
  ]
];


var searchValue = "10,11";

var FOUND = bookingArr.find(function(post, index) {
  if (post.bookingid == 11)
    return true;
});


console.log(FOUND)
```

expected result

```
[ { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "ab" },
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "cd" },
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "ef" },
    { name:"user 2", bookingid:11, product: "ui" }]
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @iota i have updated the expected result please check

Comment: Why does the `bookingArr` contain arrays and not objects directly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for better performance after flattening the array.

```js
let bookingArr = [[
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "ab" },
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "cd" }
],[
    { name:"user 2", bookingid:11, product: "ui" },
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "ef" }
],
[
    { name:"user 3", bookingid:12, product: "ui" },
    { name:"user 4", bookingid:13, product: "ef" }
]];
let searchValue = "10,11";
let set = new Set(searchValue.split(",").map(Number)); // for faster lookup
let res = bookingArr.flat().filter(x => set.has(x.bookingid));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: If the `searchValue` is somehow not convertible to a `Number`, then it would be a problem. I would rather prefer converting the `bookingId` into a `String`.

Comment: is it possible to get non matched records like bookingid 12 and 13 [ { name: 'user 3', bookingid: 12, product: 'ui' }, { name: 'user 4', bookingid: 13, product: 'ef' }, ]

Comment: @itsme You can just check for elements not in the `Set`: https://jsfiddle.net/bdc3x1em/

Comment: how can i get no matched search value https://jsfiddle.net/cesm0tbn/

Comment: @itsme If you have another issue, it is recommended to ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code:

```js
const bookingArr = [[
  { name: 'user 1', bookingid: 10, product: 'ab' },
  { name: 'user 1', bookingid: 10, product: 'cd' },
], [
  { name: 'user 2', bookingid: 11, product: 'ui' },
  { name: 'user 1', bookingid: 10, product: 'ef' },
],
[
  { name: 'user 3', bookingid: 12, product: 'ui' },
  { name: 'user 4', bookingid: 13, product: 'ef' },
]];


const searchValue = '10,11';

const sv = searchValue.split(',').map(Number);

const FOUND = bookingArr.flat().filter(({ bookingid }) => sv.includes(bookingid));

console.log(FOUND);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
let bookingArr = [
  [
    { name: 'user 1', bookingid: 10, product: 'ab' },
    { name: 'user 1', bookingid: 10, product: 'cd' },
  ],
  [
    { name: 'user 2', bookingid: 11, product: 'ui' },
    { name: 'user 1', bookingid: 10, product: 'ef' },
  ],
  [
    { name: 'user 3', bookingid: 12, product: 'ui' },
    { name: 'user 4', bookingid: 13, product: 'ef' },
  ],
];

var searchValue = '10,11';

var searchIds = searchValue.split(',');

var FOUND = [];

bookingArr.forEach((el) => {
  el.forEach((el2) => {
    searchIds.forEach((num) => {
      if (num == el2.bookingid) {
        FOUND.push(el2);
      }
    });
  });
});

console.log(FOUND);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following with `filter` and `Set` will work :-

```js
let bookingArr = [
  [{
      name: "user 1",
      bookingid: 10,
      product: "ab"
    },
    {
      name: "user 1",
      bookingid: 10,
      product: "cd"
    }
  ],
  [{
      name: "user 2",
      bookingid: 11,
      product: "ui"
    },
    {
      name: "user 1",
      bookingid: 10,
      product: "ef"
    }
  ],
  [{
      name: "user 3",
      bookingid: 12,
      product: "ui"
    },
    {
      name: "user 4",
      bookingid: 13,
      product: "ef"
    }
  ]
];


var searchValue = "10,11";

function logic(arr, searchValue) {
  let searchInputs = searchValue.split(',');
  let searchSet = new Set(searchInputs.map(val => parseInt(val)));
  let output = bookingArr.flat().filter(curr => searchSet.has(curr.bookingid))
  return output;
}


console.log(logic(bookingArr, searchValue));
```

Comment: I would prefer `filter` over `reduce` in this situation. Any specific reasons you went with `reduce`?

Comment: You’re right. Can you edit it ? Else I will do it later.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply flatten the array and filter out the desired results.
Also, I've create a `Set` out of the search value for making the code more performant.

```js
let bookingArr = [
  [
    { name: 'user 1', bookingid: 10, product: 'ab' },
    { name: 'user 1', bookingid: 10, product: 'cd' },
  ],
  [
    { name: 'user 2', bookingid: 11, product: 'ui' },
    { name: 'user 1', bookingid: 10, product: 'ef' },
  ],
  [
    { name: 'user 3', bookingid: 12, product: 'ui' },
    { name: 'user 4', bookingid: 13, product: 'ef' },
  ],
];

const searchValue = "10,11"

const searchSet = new Set(searchValue.split(","))

const res = bookingArr.flat().filter(b => searchSet.has(String(b.bookingid)))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: @itsme I've posted an answer there, please check if that solves your problem.