# How could i get Not matched String in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, set, reduce

I have a booking array and I have to search inside the array using `searchValue` .

here we have to check the booking id field. if booking id and `searchValue` matched we have to push that object into the result array.

Working code

1. result array example below

   let searchValue = "12,13,15"

Result:

```
[{ name:"user 3", bookingid:12, product: "ui" },
    { name:"user 4", bookingid:13, product: "ef" }]
```

Expected Output:

12,13 matched in booking array so we have to get NotMatchedsearchValue = "15" could you please help here

```js
let bookingArr = [
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "ab" },
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "cd" },

    { name:"user 2", bookingid:11, product: "ui" },
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "ef" },

    { name:"user 3", bookingid:12, product: "ui" },
    { name:"user 4", bookingid:13, product: "ef" },
];
let searchValue = "12,13,15";
let set = new Set(searchValue.split(",").map(Number)); // for faster lookup
let res = bookingArr.filter(x => set.has(x.bookingid));
console.log(res);

// how can i get not matched searchValue 
// expected result notmatchedsearchValue ="15"
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cesm0tbn/)

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee my search value searchValue = "12,13,15" and i found bookings for 12 and 13 now i have to get not found booking string so which means we don't have booking details for 15

Comment: @itsme Ya got it, I've posted an answer, please see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation here is different when compared to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67023327/how-can-i-search-inside-array-of-array-object-in-javascript/67023703?noredirect=1#comment118596869_67023703). So, here you need to make a `Set` out `bookingArr` and not out of `searchVal`.

```js
let bookingArr = [
  { name: "user 1", bookingid: 10, product: "ab" },
  { name: "user 1", bookingid: 10, product: "cd" },

  { name: "user 2", bookingid: 11, product: "ui" },
  { name: "user 1", bookingid: 10, product: "ef" },

  { name: "user 3", bookingid: 12, product: "ui" },
  { name: "user 4", bookingid: 13, product: "ef" },
];

let searchValue = "12,13,15";
let set = new Set(bookingArr.map((b) => b.bookingid));
let res = searchValue
  .split(",")
  .map(Number)
  .filter((s) => !set.has(s))
  .join();
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @itsme Please check if this solves your problem, let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I am expected string output anyway thanks

Comment: @itsme you can simply `join` the result, updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The OP was almost there. Of cause ***for each*** array item's `bookingid` one has to `delete` this number-value from `set` which was generated before. Then one just needs to create an ***Array from*** the mutated `set` and `join` its items/values again in order to get the final string-value result.

The OP's code with some minor changes ...

```js
let bookingArr = [
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "ab" },
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "cd" },

    { name:"user 2", bookingid:11, product: "ui" },
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "ef" },

    { name:"user 3", bookingid:12, product: "ui" },
    { name:"user 4", bookingid:13, product: "ef" },
];
let searchValue = '12,13,15';

let set = new Set(searchValue.split(',').map(Number)); // for faster lookup

bookingArr.forEach(item => set.delete(item.bookingid));

let notmatchedSearchValue = Array.from(set).join(',');

console.log({ searchValue, notmatchedSearchValue });
// expected result notmatchedsearchValue = '15'
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

A more generic approach would implement a reducer function, featuring a filter-process which is agnostic to an array-items property-name. This reducer also does achieve both tasks at once, filtering the array items via a custom property-name(`key`) and providing the final string-value of missing (non matching) values ... something like ...

```js
function collectMatchingItemAndMissingValue(collector, item) {
  const { key, searchValues, missingValues, matchingItems } = collector;
  const value = item[key];

  if (searchValues.has(value)) {

    matchingItems.push(item);
    missingValues.delete(value);    
  }
  return collector;
}

function getMatchingItemsAndMissingValues(arr, key, searchValues, castValue) {
  searchValues = new Set(
    searchValues.split(',').map(castValue)
  );
  const {
    missingValues,
    matchingItems,
  } = arr.reduce(collectMatchingItemAndMissingValue, {
    key,
    searchValues,
    missingValues: new Set([...searchValues]),
    matchingItems: [],
  });
  return {
    matchingItems,
    missingValues: [...missingValues].join(', '),
  };
}

const bookingArr = [
  { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "ab" },
  { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "cd" },
  { name:"user 2", bookingid:11, product: "ui" },
  { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "ef" },
  { name:"user 3", bookingid:12, product: "ui" },
  { name:"user 4", bookingid:13, product: "ef" },
];
const searchValues = '12, 13, 15';
const castValue = str => Number(str.trim());
const {

  matchingItems,
  missingValues,

} = getMatchingItemsAndMissingValues(bookingArr, 'bookingid', searchValues, castValue);

console.log({ matchingItems, missingValues, searchValues });

console.log({
  ...getMatchingItemsAndMissingValues(
    bookingArr,
    'product',
    'xy, ui, mn, qr, ef',
    str => str.trim(),
  ),
  searchValues: 'xy, ui, mn, qr, ef'
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @itsme ... do you see how close your approach already was?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```js
for (let result of res) {
    set.delete(result.bookingid);
}
```

Then, `set` will only contain the values that were not returned -- in this case, only `15`.

If you want to preserve the values in `set`, you can also clone the set with something like `let nset = new Set(set);`, and then use `nset` in place of `set` in the for loop.

If you want a one-liner, inspired by @Barmar:

```js
[...set].filter(x => !res.some(y => y.bookingid == x)).join(",");
```

Comment: I should get the string value

Comment: You can also use `[...set].filter()` to filter out the elements that are in `res`

Comment: @itsme To turn the filtered set into a string, just run `[...set].join(",")`.

Comment: @itsme I've updated my answer with a one-liner that does everything you need it to do!

Comment: This is not time efficient for every item in the set the code checks all the items in `bookingArr`, this is an `O(n*m)` solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd be fine making a shallow copy of your new set as an array, we can use the array `some()` method and negate it using `!` to find any IDs from that set that do not exist in `bookingArr`.

```js
let bookingArr = [
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "ab" },
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "cd" },

    { name:"user 2", bookingid:11, product: "ui" },
    { name:"user 1", bookingid:10, product: "ef" },

    { name:"user 3", bookingid:12, product: "ui" },
    { name:"user 4", bookingid:13, product: "ef" },
];
let searchValue = "12,13,15";
let set = new Set(searchValue.split(",").map(Number)); // for faster lookup
let res = bookingArr.filter(x => set.has(x.bookingid));
// console.log(res);
let notMatchedSearchValues = [...set].filter(y => !bookingArr.some(x => y === x.bookingid));

notMatchedSearchValues.forEach(id => console.log(`notMatchedSearchValue: ${id}`));
```